# Notification Priority Levels

Tags: design, notification, push-notification

I want to notify users and am wondering which option to choose.

The first option shows an icon with a flag indicating that there are notifications.

For example:

[image: Notification alert in top bar with open notification tray]

The second one shows popups like in this picture :

[image: "toast" style popup notifications]

**Under which circumstances is one better than the other?**

As a side note What the 2 types are called?

Comment: Welcome to stack UX. Your question is borderline about JS implementation which is categorized as off topic on this Stack. However I could see that with some question editing you could re-frame the question to focus on the comparison of both examples from a UX perspective rather than the implementation, which is suited to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

The first notification type requires the user to act in order to see the notifications. This works well when the information hidden is not required to complete a task. It's similar to seeing that you have items in your Outlook inbox. (See below)

[image]

I'm told that I have unread emails but it doesn't block me from doing other tasks.

Popups, on the other hand, are when you want to interfere with the user's workflow and force him to act on the notification.